# Identifying a global Facebook page from API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook recently launched Global pages for brands:

http://www.facebook-studio.com/news/item/announcing-a-new-pages-structure-for-global-brands

These pages have regional aliases. For example, http://www.facebook.com/asos.france points to the ASOS global page, but only shows French content.

My questions is: is it possible to identify via Facebook's API, whether a given page URL is

1. A regional version of a global page, or
2. A standard page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Querying this with the Graph API will get you there:

```
/PAGE_NAME_OR_ID?fields=global_brand_children.username,global_brand_parent_page
```

Three examples to replace `PAGE_NAME_OR_ID` with in the above query:

- `asos.france` returns a JSON object with `global_brand_parent_page` populated. It is a regional alias. The top-level global page is given.
- `asos` returns a JSON object with an array of `global_brand_children`. It is the top level global page. The children show all the regional aliases.
- `cocacola` returns only an id. This is a stand-alone page.

Answer (score 0):

As the Facebook Graph API documentation states

> You need to be the admin of root page for child pages in order to read the global_brand_children edge for a page.

However, I think there is another way to answer this question, if you don't have that level of access. If you use this query:

```
GET /v2.5/{id}?fields=global_brand_root_id,parent_page
```

If either of those fields are present/non-empty then you can safely deduce that the page in question has a parent, either a **Global Page Root** or a **Locations Parent**.

Now, understanding the distinctions between Global Pages and Locations (aka Parent-Child) is worthy of further investigation but from what I understand–so far–they are mutually exclusive. Either a page is part of Global Pages or Locations, but not both.

From what I have read, a Global Page is **reserved for large brands** which need country/region/language-specific pages, like Coca-cola (mentioned above), while Locations would be for more local properties like hotels, retail stores, etc. Clickz had a pretty good [blog post](https://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/2364845/how-to-manage-facebook-pages-as-a-multi-unit-brand) on this, if you need to understand the distinction in more detail.